# QUnit Test - Knockout observableArray not evaluating properly

Tags: knockout.js, qunit

I am having a strange problem where this test fails off and on for no apparent reason and I am not sure what is going on.  Sometimes I will refresh the test and it will pass.  Other times, without changing anything, it will fail.  Was wondering if someone can explain what is going on.

Here is some sample code:

```
var viewModel = function() {
  return { TestDummy: ko.observable() };
};

QUnit.test("Test 1", function () {
    var curModel = new viewModel();
    validationTestCore.testMaxLength(curModel.TestDummy, '12345');

    QUnit.equal(curModel.TestDummy.errorMessages().length, 1); 
});
```

You can see that curModel.TestDummy is an observable.  This observable is passed into validationTestCore.testMaxLength, where the errorMessages observableArray is appended to it like this:

```
TestDummy.errorMessages = ko.observableArray();
TestDummy.errorMessages.push({ errorMessage: 'hello'});
```

When the test does fail, the QUnit results shows that the length is evaluating to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the rest of your view model?  I'm assuming that you at least have some knockout-validation validations configured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Knockout.js.

But, the general cause of problems like this, is because your tests are non-atomic.
The sucess or failure of a previous test, is influencing others.

To make sure about test atomicity, QUnit store in [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) the failing tests. And on the next run, it will first execute the failing tests, and after the remaining. That approach provide a different test execution order. If your test is not atomic, it will fail.

For more understanding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/PmkFR/)

```
var truth = false;

test( "always fine test", function() {
  truth = !truth;
  ok( true, "Passed!" );
  console.log("always fine test");
});

test( "will toggle error test", function() {
  truth = !truth;
  ok( truth, "Passed!" );
  console.log("will toggle error test");
});
```

Executing the entire test several times, gives new results.

To avoid that behavior, and execute the tests in order which it appears. 
You can use the `QUnit.config.reorder = false`, but this is not recommended.